# How can I get the correct orientation of the point array?

Tags: python, vtk, paraview

I'm having trouble using the VTK library in Python. I tried adding the data array to the VTK model, but found that the data was oriented incorrectly and was pointed randomly.
Here is the basic code I use:

```
import vtk
from vtk.numpy_interface import dataset_adapter as dsa
import numpy as np

fileName = "E:\VS Code\Filedata.vtk"

reader = vtk.vtkUnstructuredGridReader()
reader.SetFileName(fileName)
reader.Update()
mesh = reader.GetOutput()

# Create a 3D array
array_shape = (58924, 3)
array = np.random.rand(*array_shape).astype(np.float32)

# Add data set and write VTK file
meshNew = dsa.WrapDataObject(mesh)
meshNew.PointData.append(array, "vel")

writer = vtk.vtkUnstructuredGridWriter()
writer.SetFileName("Filedata.1.vtk")
writer.SetInputData(meshNew.VTKObject)
writer.Write()
```

I predict that after trying the above procedure, viewing the "vel" array in the VTK file using the glyph function in paraview will have the correct orientation aligned with the model shape, i.e. the velocity direction will be correct and make physical sense as shown in Figure 2 . The current orientation is still incorrect, as shown in Figure 1.

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

Comment: Did you set the `Orient` mode and associated array in your glyph in ParaView ? This is in the advanced properties

Comment: Hello Nico Vuaille.
Orient mode This function does not appear in the Orientation menu.
In the Orientation menu, there is only the Orientation Array menu, and only "NO Orientation Array" and "Vel" can be selected.

Comment: Yeah, indeed. But I do not see why it should be aligned with anything from the model. Those are random vectors, with components inside [0, 1), no ? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html

Comment: The purpose of establishing this model is so that the program can extract the velocity direction from the '' vel '' vector field during subsequent simulations.
The current problem is that the direction of the velocity field ''vel'' is random, which causes the simulation results to be wrong when simulated in subsequent programs.
I learned that the "np. random" function randomly gives an array and does not give a direction according to the model or the flow of the fluid. So now I want to find a way to see if I can use Python or Paraview to achieve the goal.